# Type error when creating record with strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have the following controller action

```
def create
  @user= user.new(user_params)
  ...
end

private
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :device)
end
```

the user model holds a foreign key to the devices table as such

```
class user < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :device
end
```

device has a `has_many` attribute on user also.

when I attempt to create a new user with form details

`user[username] = 'test'` and `user[device] = 1`

I get a type error `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch Device(#37560060) expected, got String(#15955200)`

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `form_for` in your new user template and pass the new `@user` object to it and also define input attributes like below

```
<%= form_for @user, create_user_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
    <%= f.text_field :device_id %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

and also change your strong parameter `:device` to `:device_id` as pragma told above

Answer (score 0):

Change 'device' to 'device_id'

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :device_id)
end
...
user[device_id] = 1
```